# differential equation , reduction of order help

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reduction-of-order-ode

i tried finding the second linear independant solution and have got close to it i believe how ever i still have some stuff in the way which i can seem to get rid of , and also i was wondering how would i also show with evidence that this is the correct second independent solution. [image: this is the question]

> $$(t-1)x''(t) -  (2t-1)x'(t) + 2x(t) = (t-1)^2$$
>
> $$x(2) = 0 \quad \quad \text { and } \quad\quad x'(2) = 1$$
>
> where  you are given that one independent solution to the homogeneous equation is $c^{2t}$

$(a)$ Use the method of reduction of order to show that the other independent solution is $2t-1.$